# Regular Expression rename

Tags: regex, ant

I am writing an Ant script that moves the contents of one directory to another one. In addition to just moving the files, I also have to rename the files.

There are some files that have the structure name1_ab_cd.properties and some files have the structure name2_ab.properties. What I essentially have to do is remove everything from the first _ until the end and replace it with properties.

So, the files must be named like name1.properties and name2.properties. Currently, my implementation is as follows:

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)_.*_.*(.*)" to="\1.properties\2" />
```

This works for files that have two _'s, but not for the ones that have one _ . name1_ab_cd.properties would be renamed to name1.properties, however, name2_ab.properties would remain as is. If I make it like so:

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)_.*(.*)" to="\1.properties\2" />
```

then, only name2_ab.properties would be renamed to name2.properties, however, name1_ab_cd.properties would remain as is.

I need a way to just select the first _ and then select until the end of the string. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="([^_.]+)[^.]*(\.properties)" to="\1\2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are greedy. That is, they'll match the largest possible match. Imagine a string like this:

```
this_is_a_test
```

and I want the first part to the first underscore:

```
this_is_a_test =~ s/^(.*)_/$1/
```

The parentheses set won't just match `this`, but `this_is_a_test` because that's the largest match. That's because I am telling it to match everything up to an underscore.

The basic way around something like that is to exclude the character I don't want. For example:

```
this_is_a_test =~ s/^([^_]*)_/$1/
```

Replaces the `.*` which matches any series of characters to [^_]* which matches any series of characters ***except*** underscores. That way, you're only matching up to the first underscore.

In fact, we could eliminate the underscore after the grouping:

```
this_is_a_test =~ s/^([^_]*)/$1/
```

So, all you have to do is change your mapper from:

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="(.*)_.*(.*)" to="\1.properties\2" />
```

to

```
<mapper type="regexp" from="^([^_]*).*\.properties$" to="\1.properties"/>
```

The `^([^_]*)` will match everything from the beginning of the line until the first underscore. The `\.properties$` will make sure the file name ends with `.properties`.

I'm not sure what your second grouping was doing. (Are you trying to move part of the string after the `.properties` suffix?) Instead, I just did it as you stated in your initial query.